# How to use a case insensitive function in if statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently coding a discord bot using the discord.py library, and I want my bot to react certains reactions when he detects a word inside a message without checking the capitals letters.

I already have found a class in order to do that, but for an unknown reason, when I use this class, the bot doesn't detect the string inside of of message, he detects it only when it's the message alone...

Here is the class I've found:

```
class CaseInsensitively(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.__s = s.lower()
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__s)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
           other = other.__s
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
          try:
             other = other.lower()
          except:
             pass
        return self.__s == other
```

And here is the usage of the class:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    test = "Test"
    if CaseInsensitively(test) in {CaseInsensitively(message.clean_content)}:
        await discord.Message.add_reaction(message, "")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

I'm using python 3.7.1 on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You are also using classes wrong here. `await discord.Message.add_reaction(message, "")` should be `await message.add_reaction(react)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is these extra braces

```
{CaseInsensitively(message.clean_content)}
```

This is no longer a string, it is a `set`. So it is checking if your exact string is contained in that set, it is no longer doing substring checking

```
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'      # substring check
True
>>> 'foo' in {'foobar'}    # set containment
False
>>> 'foo' in {'foo'}       # set containment
True
```

In my opinion, the class is unnecessary anyway, this should be sufficient

```
if test.lower() in message.clean_content.lower():
```

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't think about the `lower()` fonction...
It's working fine now, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments you've received. The case insensitivity you've addded is a bit overkill. `.lower()` will suffice:

```py
if "test" in message.content.lower():
```

Also, when you're adding the reaction, you need the message object that was sent, not just some "empty" arbitrary message object:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "test" in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction("")
    await client.process_commands(message) # in the same way here you've referenced message
```

`discord.Message` is simply the base class, you don't need to create a new instance of it when you can refer to one that already exists; `message`

---

**References:**

- [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)

Comment: Oh thanks, i didn't know that !
I have never used classes before using the discord.py library...

Comment: No worries, referencing the right objects takes a bit of getting used to in d.py, but one day it'll just click and make sense. Good luck with the bot :^)